# Carmichael function available in PARI / GP?

Tags: math-software, carmichael-function

Is the Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$ available in PARI / GP or do I have to
program it ?

I know the command znorder, but this does not seem to be enough to calculate the
carmichael function.

I have programmed the function, but it would nevertheless be nice to know, if there is an easier way to calculate $\lambda(n)$.

Comment: Have you tried asking `pari-users` list from http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/lists-index.html? Anyhow, one of PARI/GP experts just told me that you can use `znstar()`, specifically `lambda(n)=znstar(n)[2][1]`. But this computes more than what you actually need (the generators).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried asking [pari-users list](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/lists-index.html)? Anyhow, one of PARI/GP experts just told me that you can use `znstar()`, specifically `lambda(n)=znstar(n)[2][1]`. But this computes more than what you actually need (the generators).

(Pasting my old comment as a CW answer to remove this from the unanswered queue)